# Google Identityによるアプリケーションの制御について

Tags: google-cloud-platform

現在Azure Appserviceのアプリケーションの認証を[1]の方法を利用して、Googleの認証を利用している状態です。

今後、Google Identityを利用して、ユーザーごとにアプリの接続の制限をかけたいと考えております。

ここで以下3点のことを質問させてください。

・[2]の手順で登録するアプリケーションは[1]のGoogle認証を使用する際に登録したアプリケーションと同じで良いのか

・Google Identityでの設定手順の詳細

・設定する際の留意点

以上になります。よろしくお願いいたします。

[1]https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-google

[2]https://jp.mathworks.com/help/mps/server/configure-access-control-using-google-identity-platform-payg.html